# An idea for a data structure that will store sentences that differ in one word

Tags: data-structures

I have a file consist lot of lines like:

1. John is running at night
2. John is not walking at night
3. Jack is running at night
4. Jack is waiting for someone
5. John is waiting for someone

and I need to write a program that will group similar sentences and print them to a file.
Similar sentences are sentences that only a single word has been changed between them.

For example, the output file should look like:

1. John is running at night
2. Jack is running at night

The changing word was: Jhon, Jack

4. Jack is waiting for someone
5. John is waiting for someone

The changing word was: Jhon, Jack

I thought to implement it by parsing the file and arrange the strings in groups of a number of words in each string(all string that has 6  words will be group together and all string that has 5 words will be group together and so on)

After arranging to groups I can split each string to a set of words and compare each string to another string and check for a match.

I think my solution is not efficient.

Does anyone have a better solution he can think of?

Comment: When you say Jhon twice, did you mean John?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume there are *M* sentences with an average of *N* words each. For every sentence we wish to produce a list of indices of other sentences (up to *M* - 1) that differ by exactly one word. Thus, the input size is *O(MN)* words and the output size is *O(M²)* numbers. Here is an algorithm that runs in *O(MN + M²)* and is therefore optimal.

First, read all the sentences, split them into words and index the words in a hash tables. Thus, we can think of sentences of arrays. To help our thought process, we can further think of sentences as Latin lowercase strings by replacing each initial word with a letter (this works up to 26 distinct words).

Now we wish to be able to query each pair of strings (*A, B)* in *O*(1) and ask "do *A* and *B* differ by exactly one letter"? To anwser,

- let *l* be the common length of *A* and *B*;
- let *p* be the length of the common prefix between *A* and *B*;
- let *s* be the length of the common suffix between *A* and *B*;
- then notice that *A* and *B* differ by exactly one letter if *l = p + s + 1*.

Therefore, our algorithm boils down to determining, in constant time, the length of the common prefix and common suffix for every pair of strings. We show how to do this for prefixes. The same approach works for suffixes, e.g. by reversing the strings.

First, sort the strings and measure the common prefixes between each consecutive pair. For example:

```
banana
               > common prefix 3 ("ban")
band
               > common prefix 4
bandit
               > common prefix 1
brother
               > common prefix 7
brotherly
               > common prefix 0
car
```

Now, suppose you want to query the common prefix between "band" and "brotherly". This will be the minimum numeric value between "band" and "brotherly", or *min*(4, 1, 7) = 1. This can be achieved with [range minimum queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query) in *O(M)* processing time and and *O*(1) per query, although simpler implementations are available in *O(M log M)* preprocessing time.